# Randomize Sprite moment Help needed

Tags: game-design, android, game-mechanics

I am new to Android, I am developing a fighting game in Android with AndEngine. Now I want my enemies to mimic my player behavior and on base of score they should come up with different tactics.

I need to write an AI script. Please help me in that. I want to make my enemies intelligent that they can destroy my player and also engage him in game too.

Comment: This is too vague. -1.

Comment: What do you want to randomize? Behavior? Look? Time of appearance? You have to be way more specific.

Comment: I want to randomize behavor, time, look, appearance

Comment: You need a lot more detail then.

Comment: NPCs that act intelligent and can destroy your player is quite different from randomized movement though.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: `sprite.x += rand()%100 - 50; sprite.y += rand()%100 - 50`

Comment: Your new (see: edited) question has an entire field of related study, I suggest you show us what you've tried first.

Comment: I told you i am new STOP NEGATIVE VOTING PLEASE!!!

Comment: @Aizaz, people are downvoting your question because writing an AI script is a huge chunk of work, and isn't something that can be answered on a site like this.

Answer (score 1):

Given the amount of information in your question.

Run a random number generator.
Input that value as a parameter to a function that generates parameters for your characters based on the input value.

Then use those generated values as construction information for your enemy character factory.